Possible to petition at district court/court of federal claims against IRS after losing in tax court?
A quick question. So assume I petition against IRS in tax court and then the court rules in favor of IRS. And then I also lose the appeals process at tax court. So let's say I then pay the tax I'm disputing to be able to petition at federal non-specialised courts. Is it possible to then petition against IRS at a district court or court of federal claims? Or am I barred from doing so after I lose in tax court?

Seems covered in https://www.ustaxcourt.gov/petitioners_after.html


am I barred from doing so after I lose in tax court?

Yes. While you can file a motion for reconsideration in tax court and can appeal your case to the relevant U.S. Circuit Court of Appeals (unless it is a "small tax case"), you cannot litigate the case in U.S. District Court. The doctrine of res judicata bars re-litigation of a case that has already been litigated on the merits in U.S. Tax Court.

Worth mentioning that small tax cases in USTC cannot be appealed (it's essentially binding arbitration).

@littleadv Good point.

@ohwilleke Thanks and this is so even though I pay the tax and file a petition to district court for my refund claim to be considered as a brand new case? Not an attempt to appeal the tax court decision but a brand new litigation. They would still dismiss it based on the past ruling of the tax court?

@Cognitive_impotence The judge would dismiss your case. Might even sanction you for bringing a frivolous claim.

@Cognitive_impotence if the Tax Court ruled against you then the IRS would be within their rights to deny your claim for refund. You would have no grounds to sue, and as said - might even be punished for doing so (although your attorney would probably not let you do that to begin with).
